# Django Rest Framework - Ordering a nested reverse lookup serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to order/sort a serializer `availability` that is both a reverse lookup and nested inside `unit` serializer? For example, I wish to order `availability` by `start_time` instead of `id`.

Below is what I tried but I get `.order_by('-start_time')' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

**Serializers**

```
class AvailabilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    staff = StaffSerializer() 

    class Meta:
        model = Availability
        fields = ['id','start_time', 'end_time','staff']

class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = ['company', 'logo']

class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    availability = AvailabilitySerializer(source='availability_set.order_by('-start_time')', many=True)
    manager = ManagerSerializer()


    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'manager', 'availability']
```

Comment: in your Availability model just try to add ordering = ('-start_time')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the field and provide the serializer with your own queryset and then return the data:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField


class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    availability = SerializerMethodField()
    manager = ManagerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'manager', 'availability']

    def get_availability(self, instance):
        queryset = instance.availability_set.order_by('-start_time')
        return AvailabilitySerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

[SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thank you very much :)